# Sticky note widgets each have their cursor blinking as if active all together

Tags: macos, dashboard-widget, dashboard

Using a new MBP Retina at work with Mountain Lion. I always used the sticky dashboard widgets to organize my oh-so-chaotic life on my Lion MBP.

Now that I use them in 10.8 (around 16-20 stickies) I noticed that all of them now have their cursor "on" which is really distracting!

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot?

Comment: I'd rather not, since my stickies contain both confidential and personal info.
Just imagine 16 stickies all with their cursor blinking at their last known position. ;)

Comment: Then it's hard for us to get an overview. Can you provide a screenshot and blur out the info or describe your issue a bit better and in more detail?

Comment: Ok, so just now, almost half of the stickies had lost all their text. Hooray for the file in dropbox from which I copied their contents.
This weird side-mess-up aside, I noticed that the cursor issue stopped once I removed a sticky and added a new one instead.
No idea when or if this issue will surface again.

Comment: I got the exact same problem, blinking cursors everywhere, on the dashboards sticky posts and in the converter tool.
Here's a gif -> [Annoying dashboard cursor](http://nattestorm.co.uk/andet/dashboard_widgets.gif)

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem, too. It's SO annoying. I'm on a Macbook Pro (Early 2008) with OS X Mavericks and my dashboard has about 9 sticky notes that appear to be active with the blinking cursor, but it's not just limited to them. Other widgets such as the Dictionary and translator, and others I have downloaded that have the ability to write something, also blink. At least with those I can click on a section of the widget to stop the blinking cursor, but not with the sticky notes.